# Apps usually crash when I try to post photos (Messenger, Instagram)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640, messenger, crash, instagram

Ive had an issue for as long as I can remember where whenever I try to upload photos to messenger or instagram, the app just crashes. Please help.

Lumia 640
Windows 10 Mobile
Version: 1703
OS Build: 10.0.15063.483

Comment: Does it happen with any other apps? Have you tried resetting or reinstalling those apps? Have you tried resetting your phone? When did it start happening? Are the apps up-to-date?

Comment: It doesnt hapoen with other apps, just the ones listed. I have reset both of the apps. Phone has been reset. Apps are up to date.

Comment: Are the pictures you're trying to upload in phone memory or on a micro SD card? If on a memory card, try copying them to phone memory and then uploading. Also try checking the card for errors in a PC.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? It happens to me too...